# HTML/ CSS - FORMATAR INFORMAÇÕES

Tags: css, html5

Olá, pessoal!

Estou aprendendo HTML/CSS e gostaria de saber como eu faço para mostrar algumas informações no browser, desta maneira utilizando espaçamento entre as informações da esquerda e da direita na mesma linha, por exemplo:

//Alinhado à esquerda

Endereço

Bairro

Fone resid

Fone cel

//Alinhado à direita

Nacionalidade

Idade

Estado civil

---

Obrigado pela atenção de todos!

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque um [mcve] para podemos entender o que você está querendo fazer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p style="text-align:left;">
    Endereço
    <span style="float:right;">
        Nacionalidade
    </span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:left;">
    Bairro
    <span style="float:right;">
        Idade
    </span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:left;">
    Fone resid
    <span style="float:right;">
        Estado civil
    </span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:left;">
    Fone cel
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para alinhar um texto a esquerda, utilize:

```
classe{
   text-align: left;
}
```

Para alinhar a direita:

```
classe{
   text-align: right;
}
```

Para o texto ficar justificado:

```
classe{
   text-align: justify;
}
```

Para centralizar o texto:

```
classe{
   text-align: center;
}
```